# Configuring IPv6 on FreeBSD 12

Tags: networking, freebsd, dns, ipv6

I have configured my FreeBSD 12 system to use DHCP, but DNS resolution does not appear to be working for IPv6 (e.g., when I run `ping6` or `traceroute6`).

`/etc/rc.conf` (relevant lines)

```
ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
ifconfig_em0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"
rtsold_enable="YES"
```

Example output of `ping6 freebsd.org`:

```
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 9169:36d8:483c:b1e0:7e66:7f17:5308:d51b --> 2610:1c1:1:606c::50:15
```

Any tips on how to get DNS resolution working for IPv6?

**Edit:** updated the question, since at first I wasn't sure if a cached IPv6 address was simply being used by ping6, but now it seems that IPv6 DNS resolution is working fine, but general networking using IPv6 still has major problems (namely, it is extraordinarily slow).

Comment: Cowardly downvoter(s) going to comment or not?

Answer (score 2):

That you see `2610:1c1:1:606c::50:15` in the output means that the AAAA lookup for `freebsd.org` *did* work.

The BSD `ping6` command, itself, may not be doing PTR lookups (NetBSD doesn't), but you can verify the system resolver is also working there with `nslookup`.

e.g on a NetBSD system:

```
% ping6 freebsd.org
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2001:470:30::a654:105 --> 2610:1c1:1:606c::50:15
16 bytes from 2610:1c1:1:606c::50:15, icmp_seq=0 hlim=52 time=22.948 ms
16 bytes from 2610:1c1:1:606c::50:15, icmp_seq=1 hlim=52 time=23.084 ms
```

But

```
% nslookup 2610:1c1:1:606c::50:15
5.1.0.0.0.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.c.6.0.6.1.0.0.0.1.c.1.0.0.1.6.2.ip6.arpa        name = wfe0.nyi.freebsd.org.
```

So DNS resolution is working; it's just `ping6` doesn't do the lookups.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might have just been cacheing the IP address or something. How I get ping6 to work?

Comment: On NetBSD, `man ping6` mentions the -H flag

Comment: That doesn't help, though I suspect I have bigger problems, since IPv6 is actually working, but I'm getting long delays in networking operations that use IPv6, it seems.